# Get a Maximum Date value from X tables in DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataSet with 1-3 tables, each table have a column named m_date (string)
I want to get max value from all of them using LINQ.

I know how to get each table Maximum value:

```
var maxDate=ds.Tables[index].AsEnumerable()
              .Max(x=>DateTime.Parse(x["m_date"].ToString())).ToString();
```

but I don't know how to get Max value from all the tables information

**Edit:**

I now have something like this which works:

```
DateTime maxDate=DateTime.MinValue;

foreach  (DataTable tbl in ds.Tables)
{
     DateTime maxDateCur=ds.Tables[index].AsEnumerable()
                  .Max(x=>DateTime.Parse(x["m_date"].ToString()));
     maxDate=new DateTime[] {maxDateCur,maxDate}.Max();
}
```

but I have a feeling it could be done better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it as:

```
var maxDate = Enumerable.Range(0, ds.Tables.Count)
        .SelectMany(index => ds.Tables[index].AsEnumerable())
        .Max(dataRow => dataRow.Field<DateTime>("m_date"))
        .ToString();
```

- Uses `Enumerable.Range` to generate the indices enabling us to access each individual `DataTable`.
- Uses `SelectMany` to get a single `IEnumerable<DataRow>`
- Uses `Max` to get the maximum value and convert it to a string.

Slightly different variant would be:

```
var maxDate = Enumerable.Range(0, ds.Tables.Count)
                .Select(index =>
                    ds.Tables[index].AsEnumerable()
                        .Max(dataRow => dataRow.Field<DateTime>("m_date")))
                .Max().ToString();
```

- Uses `Enumerable.Range` to generate the indices enabling us to access each individual `DataTable`.
- Uses `Select` to get an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` consisting of the maximum `DateTime` of each `DataTable`
- Uses `Max` to get the maximum value of the of the DateTime's and then convert to a string representation.

Comment: Works Great, the only change I made is changing the field to DateTime.ParseExact, because my datetime string is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: and adding .Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<string>("col_name")))